# CouchDB: custom error page

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

Is there a way to customize error pages in CouchDB, particularly in couchapp?

When I try to load URL with undefined/misspelled view

```
http://localhost:5984/database/_design/app/_view/sample
```

CouchDB 1.2 just closes the connection:

> Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

I'd like to customize this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A partial answer was found here: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Advanced_Shows_and_Lists_Throwing_Redirects